# How do I console.log the result of a function inside within the same function?

Tags: javascript, function

Im working on making my code more concise and eliminate junk code. I made a temperature calculator that converts temperatures between Fahrenheit Celsius and kelvin. What changes to the following code would you recommend i make it more concise? and im having a hard time printing the result of the function to the console.log within the function, i would like to print something like this "10 f to c is 37.7778" i dont know how to print the result of the function into the console.log, my spider sense is telling it may have something to do with loops but im fairly new and im lost. Thank you

```
    const conversion = (abbreviation, abbreviation1, number) => {
     if (abbreviation === "c"&&abbreviation1==='f') {console.log((number * 9) / 5 + 32);} 
     else if (abbreviation==='c' && abbreviation1==='k'){console.log(number+273.15)} 
     else if (abbreviation === "f" && abbreviation1==='c'){console.log(((number - 32) * 5) / 9);} 
     else if (abbreviation === "f" && abbreviation1==='k'){console.log((number-32)/1.8+273.15)} 
     else if (abbreviation==='k'&& abbreviation1==='c'){console.log(number-273.15)} 
     else if (abbreviation==='k'  && abbreviation1==='f')
    {console.log(((number - 273.15) * 9/5 +32));
  };
console.log(number + ' '+abbreviation + ' to ' + abbreviation1+' is' + **conversion(abbreviation, abbreviation1, number)**
};
conversion("f","c", 100);
```

I tried using loops but i still cant get the result i want.

Comment: The principle is that your function should not be doing any I/O at all.  Your function should return its answer as a number.  It's up to the CALLER to decide what to do with the answer.

Comment: So how would i go about using the result of the function outside of the function. in a console.log, What you're saying is that i cant use the result inside the function but im able to us it outside the function. Im a noob so thanks for helping out

Comment: No loops necessary. Instead, calculate a canonical value. Convert the input format to kelvin, then convert the kelvin value to the output format. Write two helper functions for that, which `return` (not `console.log(…)`) their results. Also, choose better variables names than `abbreviation` and `abbreviation1`.

Comment: A function is a thing that converts something into something else.  The things going in are the parameters.  The things going out are the return.  Start thinking of your functions as "converters", and pretty soon you become adept at hooking them together to get larger chunks of work done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
const conversion = (abbreviation, abbreviation1, number) => {
    var combo = abbreviation + abbreviation1;
    console.log(number + ' '+abbreviation + ' to ' + abbreviation1);
    if( combo === 'cf' )
        return number * 9 / 5 + 32;
    if( combo === 'ck' )
        return number + 273.15;
    if( combo === 'fc' )
        return (number - 32) * 5 / 9;
    if( combo === 'fk' )
        return (number - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
    if( combo === 'kc' )
        return number - 273.15;
    if( combo === 'kf' )
        return (number - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32;
    return number;
  };
};
console.log( conversion("f","c",100) );
```

For debug purposes, you could modify this just a bit to use `number =` instead of `return`; then you could `console.log(number);` just before the final return statement.

Comment: A bit confused, so is there any way i can save the result to a variable so that i can print console.log the result in a sentence?

Comment: ??? Of course, exactly like you would store the result of ANY function call.  Just like you would write `var x = sin(1.57);`, you would write `var x = conversion(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const conversion = (abbreviation, abbreviation1, number) => {
    switch (abbreviation + abbreviation1) {
        case "cf":
            return (number * 9) / 5 + 32;
        case "ck":
            return number + 273.15;
        case "fc":
            return ((number - 32) * 5) / 9;
        case "fk":
            return ((number - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15;
        case "kc":
            return number - 273.15;
        case "kf":
            return ((number - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32;
        default:
            return "Invalid input";
    }
};

const printConversion = (abbreviation, abbreviation1, number) => {
    const result = conversion(abbreviation, abbreviation1, number);
    console.log(`${number} ${abbreviation} to ${abbreviation1} is ${result}`);
};

printConversion("f", "c", 100);
```